# Need to Install Concourse(CI/CD) on windows system

Tags: concourse, cf-bosh

I need to install Concourse(CI/CD) on my Local windows machine

Below process I followed :

- Install Bosh on local system.
- It was successfully install and while executing command at command prompt
  then it show version all "bosh" -- "version 3.0.1-712bfd7-2018-03-13T23:26:43Z".
- Try Download the concourse-lite deployment manifest file but it fails it shows below error.

[image]

Follow the below link to install Concourse :
https://concoursetutorial.com/ --- section **For Windows:**

Answer (score 2):

I don't reccomend doing this at all because you'll be swimming so far out of the main stream that you'll find tons of issues and no one is going to care enough to want to fix them.

Even if you didn't find any issues,  resources require a linux worker  for anything to work so your going to need linux anyways.

I recommend running your db, web and linux worker on linux and then running windows workers as needed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'd love windows to be a frist class citizen and run all of this on a windows server with full container support.  It looks like thought is starting to be put into this: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/2175   but until it's all done and working the above will be my guidance.    Maybe one day I can delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run it on a Windows machine, I recommend enabling Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Here is a [link to a tutorial that shows you how to do that on Windows 11](https://pureinfotech.com/install-wsl-windows-11/).

Once you do, you will be able to choose which Linux distro to install - WSL is basically a small Linux VM that runs on your Windows machine and shares resources with the main OS. TLDR; - the supported ones are Ubuntu, Debian, Kali Linux, openSUSE, and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server. You can see all supported distros by issuing (see Step 3 of the tutorial):

```
wsl --list --online
```

Here is one more [link that shows you which distros are available for WSL](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-default-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-distro-in-windows-11.12233/).

Then installation is pretty simple (Step 4 of the tutorial):

```
wsl --install -d DISTRO-NAME
```

And of course restart your computer ... 'cause its Windows :).

By doing this, you will save yourself all sort of trouble. Concourse CI heavily relies on Docker and Docker is really Linux based (only simulated on macOS). So, you need Linux. Fortunately, Microsoft has solved the compatibility problems with WSL.

Here is one more [link that shows how to install Docker on Windows using either WSL2 or Hyper-V](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AneS8ulQeKE). The author did a really good job explaining the requirements.

Best of luck.